# Rails: how to redirect user back to the search results (but the search url doesn't have query strings) after facebook login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, session, authentication

Usecase: The user(not logged in) does a search and the results are displayed, but the user login via facebook auth, and loses the previously searched results and is sent back to the search page. Currently, I am not displaying the search results, how would I go about accomplishing this? I believe the search data is saved in the session.

My mind/road block is, Is the session cleared and recreated when the User is logged in or is that saved? If it is saved, would I just have to retrieve it and then just pass those variables again?

I tried to redirect them back to the search page, but the search url doesn't contain the query strings.